# Scala vs. Java performance

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting

I've encountered a very strange discrepancy between Scala and Java performance. I've implemented an inversion counting routine in Java and then ported it line by line to Scala, because all idiomatic Scala versions (using `List` or `Stream`) were either very slow or crashing with stack overflow/out of memory error. But this version was slow as well—while the Java version takes 22ms to process an array of 100000 integers, the Scala version takes 3 seconds. Here's the relevant code from the Scala version:

```
  def mergeAndCountInversions(xs: Array[Int], aux: Array[Int], left: Int, right: Int) = {
    xs.copyToArray(aux)
    val m = left + (right - left) / 2

    var i = left
    var j = m + 1
    var inv: Long = 0

    for (k <- left to right) {
      if (i > m) {
        xs(k) = aux(j)
        j += 1
      } else if (j > right) {
        xs(k) = aux(i)
        i += 1
      } else if (aux(j) < aux(i)) {
        xs(k) = aux(j)
        j += 1
        inv += (m - i) + 1
      } else {
        xs(k) = aux(i)
        i += 1
      }
    }
    inv
  }
```

Any ideas on how to improve this routine's performance?

UPD: The poor performance of Scala version is completely my fault. The first statement unnecessarily copies whole array to auxiliary array. When changed to copy only the required part the performance is on par with Java as it's supposed to be.

Comment: Although I'm not enough of a Scala wiz to write an answer to this, consider that array indexing in Scala is calling the `apply` method on an array object – not quite the same thing as the pointer arithmetic Java performs under the hood when you use the array access syntax with square brackets!

Comment: First of all: use [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) to measure performance **after warm up**. I guess you'll get the same performance after inlining. You could also enforce inlining at compile time using [Scalaxy](https://github.com/ochafik/Scalaxy/tree/master/Loops) like this: `for(k <- left to right optimized)`.

Comment: @senia I've updated the question with the benchmark routine used

Comment: I've found that reconstructing scala's for comprehensions as tail-recursive algorithms often has performance benefits (if you can do it).  The compiler seems to be better at optimizing those.

Comment: Ah, synapse, I was just looking at your original Scala implementation of this over on CodeReview ;)  You don't fully understand tail recursion/optimisation, I think.  Have given an example, over there.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is because of the for-comprehension. It gets desugared to

```
Range(left, right).foreach { k =>
  // code...
}
```

In order to make it comparable with the Java solution, you have to replace it with a while loop.

```
var k = left

while (k <= right) {
  // code...

  k += 1
}
```

I'm pretty sure, that this solution will be on par with the Java version.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that could be the reason but performance was the same with `while`

Comment: What I don't understand is why the Scala compiler doesn't find a way to optimize the `Range(...).foreach` construct into the same underlying bytecode as what gets generated for a Java for loop...

Comment: @ErikAllik for in scala does a lot more than the usual java looping constructs. There is work being done (https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1338) to optimize the simplest cases

Comment: I tested it with for and while and while was way faster.

Comment: @drexin that's really strange. What is your environment? I'm using Scala 2.10.2 and JDK 1.6 on Mac OS X.